# ImportError: cannot import name 'FileWrapper' from 'werkzeug'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, werkzeug

```
PS C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\DeviceSync\New folder\pyRD-master> python .\app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from werkzeug import FileWrapper
ImportError: cannot import name 'FileWrapper' from 'werkzeug' (C:\Users\scanner.PSHFAST.000\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py)
```

why does this happen? and how can I fix it.

Comment: Which version of werkzeug do you use?

Comment: @ewong i think its version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileWrapper.html), "You should not use this class directly but rather use the `wrap_file()` function that uses the WSGI server’s file wrapper support if it’s available."

So your import statement (sourced from [this example](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/examples/upload.py)) should be

```py
from werkzeug.wsgi import wrap_file
```